# how is implicit index signature type checked in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out what the rules are for implicit index signatures but got stuck on this example:

Let's say we want some return type to adhere to an interface with an index signature:

```
interface A { [index: string]: string }
const getA = (): A => {
    return { a : 'a' }
}
```

This of course works because `{ a : 'a' }` is implicit `any` and `any` can be implicitly cast to everything else.

Let's instead say we're a bit more picky on what we return, perhaps it's some result with type `B` that we want to implicitly map to our interface A:

```
interface A { [index: string]: string }
interface B { b: string }
const getA = () : A => {
    return { b : 'b' } as B
}
```

This does not work, because interface B is explicitly defined as having no index signature. Is my thinking correct here? (note: I would really like this to work but perhaps it's not possible)

Resulting error:

> Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A'. Index signature is missing in
>   type 'B'.

However, and this is where I get confused, being a bit more lax on our definition of `interface A` lets us compile again:

```
interface A { [index: string]: any }
interface B { b: string }
const getA = () : A => {
    return { b : 'b' } as B
}
```

Why? Isn't the index signature is still missing on `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This of course works because { a : 'a' } is implicit any

This is wrong. `{ a : 'a' }` has type `{ a: 'a' }`.

This function doesn't have an error because TypeScript can see that you're returning a new object literal (also referred to as "fresh"). If it's a new object literal, then it can't have any other properties, so TypeScript can statically check that all its properties are assignable to the index signature type.

In the next example, the type assertion `{ b : 'b' } as B` defeats the freshness checking (a type assertion always removes all type information about the original expression). Because TypeScript can't tell if this expression is actually an alias for an expression which might have extra properties, it has to issue an error.

In the last example, you've said (`[index: string]: any]`) that you want an object for whom all properties are some type compatible with `any`. Is the object you've written an object whose properties are all compatible with `any`? Of course it is; all types have that property. So the code is OK.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your answer. I think I understand a bit more. And I have new questions :)

In the second case (`interface A { [index: string]: string }` + `{ b : 'b' } as B`) what could "an alias for an expression" be here really and is there a way to tell typescript that this is actually a plain interface that (from my view) should be equally implicitly index-able as a "fresh" object if not even more?

Comment: Also, you say in the third case (`{ [index: string]: any }`) that all _properties_ are compatible with `any`. But I can still explicitly say that the index signature should be of type `string`. That may not be they case for all objects. A weird thing to me is that I don't get an error even if I change to `{ [index: number]: any }`. Doesn't the index signature matter if the value type is `any`?

Comment: All keys in JavaScript are strings (or symbols). Numeric index signatures are just a subset of string index signatures